# Show screen using startActivity(Intent) and handler.postDelayed()

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am making an app where I need to show 5 questions in a row, but between each question I need to show the same screen containing a graphic for a fixed amount of time (after which it needs to disappear automatically). I used a for loop to create the 5 question screens which worked fine, however now I want to add the graphic screen between using a handler and the postDelayed() function but it is not working. Any ideas what is wrong with my code? Or is it not possible to switch between the screens this way?

```
        //launch questionsActivity times 5
    final Intent questionIntent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        questionIntent.putExtra("Question", currentGame.getQuestionText(i));
        questionIntent.putExtra("Player", String.valueOf(i));
        currentGame.getQuestion(i).setAnswered(true);//add 'answered' flag on question for game

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_randomizer);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(questionIntent);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 6000);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do task in handler use this below code

```
new Handler().postDelayed (() -> {

    //your code here

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use the `Viewpager` with `Fragment` read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)!